# Can I replace an AxisItem on a Qt Creator promoted pyqtgraph widget?

Tags: pyqtgraph

I place a widget in Qt Creator and promote it to a PyQtGraph *PlotWidget*. I'd like to use a custom *AxisItem* with that widget. Is there any way to replace the existing axis or do I have to subclass PlotWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a way to replace an existing axis; use a subclass as you suggested.

Comment: How do you go about using a subclass?

Can someone offer an example?

Answer (score 0):

Still there isnt a way to replace existing axis without promoting to a `PlotWidget` subclass as mentioned in the other answers. For someone looking for an example subclass for `PlotWidget` that uses x axis as `DateAxisItem` here it is:

```
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, DateAxisItem

class XDateTimeAxis_PlotWidget(PlotWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, background='default', plotItem=None, **kargs):
        super(XDateTimeAxis_PlotWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent, background=background, plotItem=plotItem, axisItems = {'bottom': DateAxisItem()}, **kargs)
```